# Chromium --alsa-ouput-device flag not working

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, alsa

I have created a virtual alsa loopback device and trying to open a youtube link in google-chrome or chromium-browser and trying to send it's audio output to that virtual device. Then using ffmpeg I am trying to capture the audio. But no matter what I do, chrome or chromium always send audio output to default built-in speakers. If I open volume control panel and change the output of the application in playback section to loopback then it works. But my requirement to be able to do it programatically by telling the chrome to send audio on which device.

Following are the commands which I tried to make it happen:

```
google-chrome --window-position=0,0 --window-size=1920,1080 --alsa-output-device=alsa_output.1.analog-stereo.monitor -kiosk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTbnmiXWs2k

google-chrome --window-position=0,0 --window-size=1920,1080 --alsa-output-device=hw:1,0 -kiosk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTbnmiXWs2k
```

And following is the ffmpeg command which is working fine:

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i alsa_output.1.analog-stereo.monitor -ac 1 -ar 16000 test.wav
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also suffered from the same problem, as Google didn't provide the complete format for ALSA output usage, so you can follow below procedure,

1. list out the plug hardware:

   ```
   aplay -L

   null
       Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
   pulse
       PulseAudio Sound Server
   default:CARD=PCH
       HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev3 Analog
       Default Audio Device
   sysdefault:CARD=PCH
       HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev3 Analog
       Default Audio Device
   front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
       HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev3 Analog
       Front speakers
   surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
       HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev3 Analog
       2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
   ```
2. Now select your plug hardware from the list and add its name to --alsa-output-device=

   ```
   --alsa-output-device='plug:surround21'
   ```

so your complete command will look like below,

```
google-chrome --window-position=0,0 --window-size=1920,1080 --alsa-output-device='plug:surround21' -kiosk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTbnmiXWs2k
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while attempting to do the same. Here's what actually worked:

```
chrome (...) --alsa-output-device=hw:0,0
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0,1,1 test.wav
```

This has chrome using (card 0, device 0) for output, which is looped back to (card 0, device 1, substream 1). The format is --alsa-output-device=hw:card,device

The opposite also works:

```
chrome (...) --alsa-output-device=hw:0,1
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0,0,1 test.wav
```

Selecting the substream (e.g. --alsa-output-device=hw:0,1,4) is impossible. If capturing with ffmpeg just assume substream 1.